# mod_rewrite redirect any instance of index.php to root of directory index.php

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

What I want to achieve:

- alias/index.php?"anything here" works all the time
- alias/"any directory"/index.php redirects to alias/index.php
- "any file.php" redirects to alias/index.php
- alias/"any directory"/"any file.php" redirects to alias/index.php

Only want to be able to execute index.php from root of alias directory

Tried:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://<host>:<port>/<alias>/index.php [NC,R,L]
```

This doesn't redirect index.php in any sub directories to alias/index.php